# Minecraft Education will not run code consistently

Tags: minecraft

I am trying to run a default  block of code with Mincecraft Education and it will not run on some computers.
I have successfully ran code on a Windows10 VM (VirtualBox) but it will not run on a few bare metal machines.
When Minecraft Education code works correctly the RED box disappears and the code will run when text is typed in the chat with the name of the function
. But, as I've mentioned the code works on some machines and not others.

[Screenshot of the RED box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JESAU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Minecraft education reached out to me with the following admin guide.

https://educommunity.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/360047118992-FAQ-IT-Admin-Guide-